# how to generate encrypted JWE with node-jose

Tags: node.js, encryption, jwt, jwe, jwk

I'm using node-jose v0.11.0 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jose) for JWK and JWE operations. I have an RSA key in JWK format that I can load into a JWK key store and also extract again. However, when I try to encrypt anything, I get into the "error2", "unsupported algorithm". How is it possible that RSA is an unsupported algorithm?

```
import * as jose from "node-jose";

const webkey = {
        "keys": [
            {
                "kty": "RSA",
                "e": "AQAB",
                "kid": "a024254d-0321-459f-9530-93020ce9d54a",
                "key_ops": [
                    "encrypt"
                ],
                "n": "jkHgYN98dlR2w7NX-gekCWaCdbxs7X4XXh52DVQrK--krwUYqRbBIUEw1bV8KX0ox6TLt-e6wpYsYYFUItSd5ySqohHRMq1IhyE2zpEC95BA9V7VrFUYnczf1bd5c-aR079aoz5JPXfqx01TzNfxWBb04SlRjsmJeY1v6JrDUI5U0FSOmnJTb3tSS6Szrvi_qOyViYp4v9V2_OVYy45kF_LQQy-pr-kP4gapXL235cieeTW6UvkhzaPT2D-JKyzVjjjgnfRXr8Ox9I9c4wpef2-5nPPeafB5EnOMpJE11KzO_8xxiTGUywPPLQagBvY35gkhQbYS2dv3NGIVSLZHFw"
            }
        ]
    };
    console.log("webkey", webkey);

    //generate key store from public JWK
    jose.JWK.asKeyStore(webkey)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("Key Store", JSON.stringify(result.toJSON()));
            let keyStore = result;

            //get the key to encrypt
            const encryptionKey: jose.JWK.Key = keyStore.get(webkey.keys[0].kid);
            const output = jose.util.base64url.encode("Hello World");
            const output2 = jose.util.asBuffer(output);

            //encrypting content
            jose.JWE.createEncrypt(encryptionKey)
                .update(output2)
                .final()
                .then((jweInGeneralSerialization) => {
                    console.log("Encryption result", JSON.stringify(jweInGeneralSerialization));
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log("error2", error.message);
                });

        }, (error) => {
            console.log("error1", error.message);
        })
```

The output is as follows:

```
'webkey', Object{keys: [Object{kty: ..., e: ..., kid: ..., key_ops: ..., n: ...}]}
'Key Store', '{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"a024254d-0321-459f-9530-93020ce9d54a","key_ops":["encrypt"],"e":"AQAB","n":"jkHgYN98dlR2w7NX-gekCWaCdbxs7X4XXh52DVQrK--krwUYqRbBIUEw1bV8KX0ox6TLt-e6wpYsYYFUItSd5ySqohHRMq1IhyE2zpEC95BA9V7VrFUYnczf1bd5c-aR079aoz5JPXfqx01TzNfxWBb04SlRjsmJeY1v6JrDUI5U0FSOmnJTb3tSS6Szrvi_qOyViYp4v9V2_OVYy45kF_LQQy-pr-kP4gapXL235cieeTW6UvkhzaPT2D-JKyzVjjjgnfRXr8Ox9I9c4wpef2-5nPPeafB5EnOMpJE11KzO_8xxiTGUywPPLQagBvY35gkhQbYS2dv3NGIVSLZHFw"}]}'
'error2', 'unsupported algorithm'
```

Update 
I digged around a bit in the actual code and found in "basekey.js" that the error is thrown because the algorithms of the library are empty.

```
 Object.defineProperty(this, "encrypt", {
 value: function(alg, data, props) {
  // validate appropriateness
  if (this.algorithms("encrypt").indexOf(alg) === -1) {
      console.log("Algorithm USED", alg
      );
      console.log("All algorithms", this.algorithms("encrypt"))
    return Promise.reject(new Error("unsupported algorithm"));
  }
```

The output here is:

```
'Algorithm USED', 'A128CBC-HS256'
'All algorithms', []
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I have an example that I added to another question:
[node-jose explanation / example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48105599/node-jose-explanation-example/53076481#53076481)

I used node-jose in a research proof, for a reflection of my c# code, I only created signed and Encrypted tokens for decryption and verification, on my server ( written in c#).

> I need to use symetric secret key or asymetric public private key pair
>   ?

I used RSA keys for Asymmetric signatures and key wrapping the Symmetric encryption details of the content. The Encryption algorithm for content encryption is a Symmetric one. The node-jose package generated the Symmetric key. The Key Wrap algorithm encrypted the Symmetric key.

The C# code I have decrypts and validates the token signature. Please note: I used the functions of the package to do all the work.

Here are my runkit notebooks for my workups:

for signing (JWS) https://runkit.com/archeon2/5bd66a8e7ee3b70012ec2e39

for encrypting (JWE) https://runkit.com/archeon2/5bd6736ff36b39001313262a

In my final, I combined the two, creating a signed token, then used the output as the payload for the encrypted one (JWS + JWE). I was successful using the c# server code in decrypting, and validating the created tokens.

JWS + JWE : https://runkit.com/archeon2/jws-jwe-integration

> How i need to generate and where i need to store keys in my server
>   node app to then allow me to sign and verify my tokens ?

```
var store = jose.JWK.createKeyStore();
await store.generate("RSA",2048,{alg:"RS256", key_ops:["sign", "decrypt", "unwrap"]});
lkey = (await store.get());
var key = lkey.toJSON(); //get public key to exchange
key.use = "sig";
key.key_ops=["encrypt","verify", "wrap"];

var pubKey = await jose.JWK.asKey(key);
key = null;
```

The Keystore can be serialized to JSON, so my concept would be to store this in Session Storage, or Local storage in a browser. Then retrieve the JSON representation and read in the Keystore.

```
var store= await jose.JWK.asKeyStore({"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"h9VHWShTfENF6xwjF3FR_b-9k1MvBvl3gnWnthV0Slk","alg":"RS256","key_ops":["sign","decrypt","unwrap"],"e":"AQAB","n":"l61fUp2hM3QxbFKk182yI5wTtiVS-g4ZxB4SXiY70sn23TalKT_01bgFElICexBXYVBwEndp6Gq60fCbaBeqTEyRvVbIlPlelCIhtYtL32iHvkkh2cXUgrQOscLGBm-8aWVtZE3HrtO-lu23qAoV7cGDU0UkX9z2QgQVmvT0JYxFsxHEYuWBOiWSGcBCgH10GWj40QBryhCPVtkqxBE3CCi9qjMFRaDqUg6kLqY8f0jtpY9ebgYWOmc1m_ujh7K6EDdsdn3D_QHfwtXtPi0ydEWu7pj1vq5AqacOd7AQzs4sWaTmMrpD9Ux43SVHbXK0UUkN5z3hcy6utysiBjqOwQ","d":"AVCHWvfyxbdkFkRBGX225Ygcw59fMLuejYyVLCu4qQMHGLO4irr7LD8EDDyZuOdTWoyP7BkM2e7S367uKeDKoQ6o1LND2cavgykokaI7bhxB0OxhVrnYNanJ1tCRVszxHRi78fqamHFNXZGB3fr4Za8frEEVJ5-KotfWOBmXZBvnoXbYbFXsKuaGo121AUCcEzFCGwuft75kPawzNjcdKhItfFrYh45OQLIO08W0fr_ByhxzWMU7yFUCELHSX5-4GT8ssq1dtvVgY2G14PbT67aYWJ2V571aSxM8DTwHrnB9tI8btbkXWt9JyVoQq13wDdo5fVN-c_5t07HBIaPoAQ","p":"8nLGa9_bRnke1w4paNCMjpdJ--eOUpZYbqEa8jnbsiaSWFwxZiOzUakIcpJ3iO0Bl28JEcdVbo7DE7mZ4M3BkOtm577cNuuK8243L7-k1a71X_ko2mQ3yF4rG2PzWAH_5P4wca1uk0Jj3PmhbkXDI6f_btm1X7Vw_U1K6jRhNbE","q":"oCe94Bed1Wzh-xgNq0hz52Z6WLf9eQlNxLzBbYkpLc_bGj9vMeGNO10qdxhWPi8ClkW9h5gBiFEk2s6aEWYRvIoZjrMYXD7xzyTNC5zcsikjNhM3FVj-kVdqUJy25o9uqgn2IwTvQr5WSKuxz37ZSnItEqK5SEgpCpjwEju_XhE","dp":"jAe2ir-0ijOSmGtZh2xMgl7nIFNRZGnpkZwDUDwSpAabJ-W3smKUQ2n5sxLdb3xUGv7KojYbJcvW6CGeurScQ_NycA9QaXgJvSe_QBjUP4bZuiDSc7DGdzfMdfl4pzAgeEZH_KBK6UrDGvIjRumMF6AEbCXaF_lX1TU7O6IdM0E","dq":"fDU2OjS2sQ5n2IAYIc3oLf-5RVM0nwlLKhil_xiQOjppF9s4lrvx96dSxti2EjYNUJQ34JBQJ_OenJ_8tx-tA8cq-RQHAYvDp75H1AjM1NO4vjh60PCbRgdAqdJQu1FkJzXgkdpC4UWSz3txRJaBWQ5hzIEtJ1Tnl5NzJQD3crE","qi":"3EoKqhKh5mwVGldSjwUGX7xnfQIfkQ4IETsQZh9jcfOFlf9f8rT2qnJ7eeJoXWlm5jwMnsTZAMg4l3rUlbYmCdg10zGA5PDadnRoCnSgMBF87d0mVYXxM1p2C-JmLJjqKhJObr3wndhvBXUImo_jV6aHismwkUjc1gSx_b3ajyU"},{"kty":"RSA","kid":"h9VHWShTfENF6xwjF3FR_b-9k1MvBvl3gnWnthV0Slk","use":"verify","alg":"RS256","key_ops":["encrypt","verify","wrap"],"e":"AQAB","n":"l61fUp2hM3QxbFKk182yI5wTtiVS-g4ZxB4SXiY70sn23TalKT_01bgFElICexBXYVBwEndp6Gq60fCbaBeqTEyRvVbIlPlelCIhtYtL32iHvkkh2cXUgrQOscLGBm-8aWVtZE3HrtO-lu23qAoV7cGDU0UkX9z2QgQVmvT0JYxFsxHEYuWBOiWSGcBCgH10GWj40QBryhCPVtkqxBE3CCi9qjMFRaDqUg6kLqY8f0jtpY9ebgYWOmc1m_ujh7K6EDdsdn3D_QHfwtXtPi0ydEWu7pj1vq5AqacOd7AQzs4sWaTmMrpD9Ux43SVHbXK0UUkN5z3hcy6utysiBjqOwQ","use":"sig"}]});
```

> How can i know which one use between OCT, EC, RSA etc ?

For this, the need your token serves may dictate this. I needed the receiver to be the one who could see the contents, so I chose RSA, for Asymmetric keys. Forgery is a bit harder.

These notebooks are somewhat a work in progress. Please review with care, as this is my interpretation and how I worked out what I needed. My hope is that they give some guidance.